# How to change text color of a Sublime 3 predefined color-scheme/theme?

Tags: css, json, colors, themes, sublimetext

Specifically, I'm using the [Boxy theme](https://github.com/oivva/st-boxy) for Sublime text 3.

I'd like to change the color of the main text and comments and I can't find a default to change to do that - just "font_face" and "font_size".

```
// my code in USER SETTINGS
{
"color_scheme": "Packages/Boxy Theme/schemes/Boxy Yesterday.tmTheme",
"ignored_packages":
[
    "Vintage"
],
"theme": "Boxy Yesterday.sublime-theme",
"theme_sidebar_font_md": true,
"theme_sidebar_size_xs": true
}
```

Comment: Too customise the color scheme see http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/customization/color_schemes.html

Answer (score 3):

- Install `PackageResourseViewer` with `Package Installer`
- go `ctrl+shift+p` and select `PackageResourseViewer: Open Resource`
- open the color scheme your using from that theme, and change whatever you want.

Comment: When you say "open the color scheme your using from that theme", do you mean the `.tmTheme` file, or the `JSON-tmTheme` file? Do both need to be changed?

Comment: nope, change only the theme file. for e.g if you wanna change the default monokai theme, then do `ctrl+shift+p` and `PackageResourseViewer: Open Resource > Color Scheme - Default > Monokai.tmTheme` and change whaever you want in it.

Answer (score 0):

Preferences > Customize Color Scheme

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).